# Import a variable from another model django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import only "is_ppc" from User models into the Order models. But I am not aware of the step on how to do it. Your assist will be highly appreciated.

Order/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from users.models import User

class Order(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    partno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank= True)
    standard = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 0)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_ppc = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

Users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_operation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supplier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_ppc = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['supplier', 'product', 'partno', 'description', 'style', 'standard', 'quantity', 'limit', 'is_ppc', 'new_stock']

        widgets = {
            'supplier': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'supplier'}),
            'product': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'product'}),
            'partno': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'partno'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'description'}),
            'style': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'description'}),
            'standard': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'standard'}),
            'quantity': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'quantity'}),
            'limit' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'limit'}),
            'is_ppc' : forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'is_ppc'}),
```

I want only to import is_ppc from User model to Order model.

Comment: this can help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do? I don't understand what you mean by "import as foreignkey".

Comment: Actually, I want to import only `is_ppc` from User model into Order model @HåkenLid

Comment: @c.grey gave you link for documentation. But you cant do it for your field, because: 'if you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.' you cant set BooleanField as unique

Comment: " I want to import only is_ppc from User model into Order model". I don't understand what that means. In python, you import from one module to another module. There's no such thing as importing into a class.

Comment: Well, I have 4 types of users as you can see. So during creating order, I want to see only is_ppc list. Currently, I only can see all list together but want to see only is_ppc user

Comment: Can't you just refactor your User model? It's probably better to have a user_type field where a user could be a ppc, operation, supplier, or admin then do a filtering somewhere like order.user.user_type = 'ppc'

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ForeignKey` by default Django will fetch the primary key. In your case that would be the id of `User` model.

You can try to check the ppc using a method in your model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ... your stuff here ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
    is_ppc = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def check_ppc(self):
        if self.user != NULL and self.user.is_ppc == True:
            self.is_ppc = True
        else:
            self.is_ppc = False
```

This way you can call the method and it will check this attribute